# Extracing Non String Text HTML VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

So, I am trying to get a date out of html using VBA in Excel, and I am having issues finding a way to extract the text that I want it appears as:

```
<SPAN id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDateCreated2>5/22/2012 8:14:08 PM</SPAN>
```

I want extract the 5/22/2012 8:14:08, but as it is not a string and in between the carats, I don't know exactly how to do it. Any tips?

Comment: You'll probably want to find a library or something for parsing HTML rather than trying to manually read it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that I was using ".innerText" incorrectly, and I was able to get it working with the following snippet.

```
Doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDateCreated2").innerText
```

Comment: And this is why it's important to include the code you've tried.  We thought you were trying to extract it from a string.  It wasn't mentioned that you had access to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for a `Mid()` formula.  If that URL/Span part in A1, put this in A2 (or wherever):

`=MID(A1,SEARCH(">",A1)+1,FIND("</",A1)-FIND(">",A1)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in VBA with split:

```
theString = "<SPAN id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDateCreated2>5/22/2012 8:14:08 PM</SPAN>"
Temp = Split(theString, "ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDateCreated2>")(1)
Final = Split(Temp, "</")(0)
```

The first Split will return an array of two parts:

```
Temp(0) = "<SPAN id=ctl00_"
Temp(1) = "5/22/2012 8:14:08 PM</SPAN>"
```

Next we Split Temp(1) to remove the closing SPAN tag and return just the date and time.